# On Category page, How can I get the category ID?

Tags: categories, id

This might be very basic question, but I can't really get the category ID on category page (actually a category page of custom type post).

Filename is `taxonomy-item-category.php` & URL is `http://www.abc.com/cat/food/`

I have tried some of the following but not working...

```
$cur_cat_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title( "food", false ) );
$cur_cat_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title( "", false ) );

get_the_category( "food" );
```

How can I get the category ID on category page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$cat_id = get_queried_object_id();` - it's that simple!

Comment: Thanks so much. It's simple but It wasn't so easy for newbie. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more easy way to find ID

[Find Category Id in Wordpress](http://www.orclage.com/how-to-find-page-post-category-tag-comment-id-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Answers should be more than outgoing links. Please answer the question in here. If the link was of help or you've taken something from there, use it for quotes or as reference.